# Adding content to the top of post's based on their category

Tags: posts, categories

I'm trying, but struggling to add a specific div to the top of a post, based on the category it is assigned.

For example, at the top of the content, if it's tagged with 'basketball' I want to add specific sponsors and information within a div.

Any ideas on the best/cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `the_content` filter for this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse420024_filter_content' );
/**
 * Conditionally adds content above the post content.
 *
 * @param  string $content The post content.
 * @return string          The filtered post content.
 */
function wpse420024_filter_content( $content ) {
    // Only run on the single post view.
    if ( is_single() ) {
        if ( has_tag( 'basketball' ) ) {
            $content = '<div>My Additional Content</div>' . $content;
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

This code is **untested**. Try it out before putting it into production.

### References

- [`the_content` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/)
- [`has_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/)
- [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/)